# How to compute the Jacobian Matrix of the next system?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, control-theory

I have a little problem with notation and I do not know how to work it out.

I have the next system

$$
\dot x = A(x)x,
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and the square matrix $A(x)_{n\times n}$ has elements depending on some of the components of $x$.

If I want to compute the Jacobian of this system about $x=0$ (zero vector), in order to study the stability of such point, how can I do it in a compact form? I mean, applying the chain rule (can I do that?) I have

$$
J=\frac{\partial A(x)}{\partial x}x+A(x)\frac{\partial x}{\partial x},
$$

the second term has meaning for me, since $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}$ is the identity matrix, so the second term at $x=0$ corresponds to $A(0)$. But what about the first term? I do not know how to "write/read or compute" $\frac{\partial A(x)}{\partial x}$ since $x$ is a vector. Is there any way to compute/write down $J$ in a "straight forward" way? With straight forward I mean, using the notation $A(x)$ (as for the second term, which result is $A(0)$) instead of splitting all the equations of the system just taking the rows of $A(x)$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're unsure about the notation you're using switch to one you do understand. I suggest writing the expression component wise $\dot x_i = \sum_k A_{ik}x_k$ and using the definition $J_{ij} = \partial \dot x_i / \partial x_j $directly.

Comment: Thanks Squid, this is what I have done (but I found it too tedious), just computing first $A(x)x$ (a vector) and then computing the partial of this vector w.r.t. $x$. I was wondering whether there is another way to compute it.

Comment: Well depends on what A is. There is no way to simplify an unspecified expression anyhow. $J_{ij} = \sum_k \frac{A_{ik}}{x_j} x_k + A_{ij}$ is as simplified as it gets. Simply as a different way of computing it all you can however evaluate $J$ column wise by viewing $\sum_k \frac{A_{ik}}{x_j} x_k$ for a fixed $j$ as the matrix product of $\partial A / \partial x_j$ and $x$, where this yields the jth column. But this is just a different way of organizing the computations and nothing characteristically different.